# Can't update NetworkManager to latest stable version

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, make

I am running Ubuntu 16.04

```
NetworkManager --version
```

returns 1.2.6

I am wanting to update to the lastest stable version (1.14.4) from [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/NetworkManager?action=show&redirect=NetworkManager).

The install documentation says "the shell command './configure && make && make install'
should configure, build, and install this package."

After much trial and error I managed to get ./configure to complete with out reporting any errors by installing the following packages:

```
apt-get install gtk-doc-tools libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev uuid-dev libnss3-dev ppp-dev libjansson-dev libcurl4-nss-dev libndp-dev libreadline-dev intltool
```

However when I run make I get:

```
mike@Ubuntu16:~/Downloads/NetworkManager-1.14.4$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mike/Downloads/NetworkManager-1.14.4'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mike/Downloads/NetworkManager-1.14.4'
  GEN      config-extra.h
  GEN      libnm-core/nm-core-enum-types.h
  CC       clients/nm_online-nm-online.o
In file included from ./shared/nm-default.h:311:0,
                 from clients/nm-online.c:34:
./libnm/NetworkManager.h:60:27: fatal error: nm-enum-types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:15265: recipe for target 'clients/nm_online-nm-online.o' failed
make[2]: *** [clients/nm_online-nm-online.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mike/Downloads/NetworkManager-1.14.4'
Makefile:17770: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mike/Downloads/NetworkManager-1.14.4'
Makefile:7864: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to install software this way.

Comment: How would you suggest?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do it at all. But if I have to, I would create a deb package.

Comment: I have found a couple of pages that give instructions on how to create a .deb package from source. They are [https://www.ostechnix.com/create-deb-file-source-ubuntu-16-04/] and [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall]. Both these pages indicate that it is necessary for 'make' to complete in order to create a .deb package from source. As I am not able to get 'make' to complete your suggestion does not seem an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running into dependency issues while building from source is normal and painful. It's better to install using **apt**

First, let's see the package that's responsible for NetworkManager

```bsh
dpkg -S $(which NetworkManager)
```

It's the **network-manager** package. Now let's see what we have avaliable

```bsh
apt policy network-manager
```

On U18 I have 1.12.4 . Try upgrading the **network-manager** package.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager
```

If you want the ubuntu 18 network-manager package you can try the below

```
# WARNING! THIS IS DANGEROUS AND MIGHT BREAK YOUR SYSTEM. IT'S BEST TO REMOVE IT AFTER INSTALLING THE PACKAGE YOU WANT
echo 'deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt uddate
sudo apt install network-manager
```

One more thing (and this is a shot in the dark); a lot of the dev packages will have the header files you need. So try

```
sudo apt install network-manager-dev
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer philn, I really appreciate the time you took to write it. I have upgraded to U18. NetworkManager --version now returns 1.10.6. All of your suggestions for upgrading NetworkManager still left me with version 1.10.6 so I am puzzled as to how you managed to get version 1.12.4 on your system. Googling the make error I get does not provide any answers. I have tried to install this source file on virtual machines for Zorin, Elementary and they both produce the same error. Do you have any suggestions as to who I could ask for the cause of this error?

Comment: All I can find is this: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2017-April/msg00017.html

Comment: On my work computer (18.04) I also get 1.10.6, so I'm assuming it's a 18.10 vs 18.04 difference. I'll see take a look at what 18.10 uses later.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the answer from the #nm on freenode.

What you need to do is run "make -k" then "make".

Then as root "make install" and you will have the latest stable version of NetworkManager on your machine :-)

I also got this patch:

```
Date: Tue, 5 Mar 2019 10:18:03 +0100
Subject: [PATCH 1/1] build: fix build dependency for generating libnm 
enum
headers before building nm-online

  CC       clients/nm_online-nm-online.o
In file included from ./shared/nm-default.h:311:0,
                 from clients/nm-online.c:34:
./libnm/NetworkManager.h:60:10: fatal error: nm-enum-types.h: No such 
file or directory
 #include "nm-enum-types.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
---
 Makefile.am | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

diff --git a/Makefile.am b/Makefile.am
index 005dbace18..b5dc5f9440 100644
--- a/Makefile.am
+++ b/Makefile.am
@@ -3880,6 +3880,7 @@ clients_nm_online_LDADD = \
$(GLIB_LIBS)

$(clients_nm_online_OBJECTS): $(libnm_core_lib_h_pub_mkenums)
+$(clients_nm_online_OBJECTS): $(libnm_lib_h_pub_mkenums)

EXTRA_DIST += \
clients/meson.build
-- 
2.20.1
```

Comment: After I applied the above patch and ran 'make' I got an error saying 'automake1.16.1 was not installed'. I rectified that by installing automake1.16.1 from here: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-main-i386/automake_1.16.1-1.1ubuntu1_all.deb.html

Comment: I then ran "sudo checkinstall" and installed the package as a deb package.

Comment: Everything appeared to be fine but on reboot NetworkManager was not running and attempts to start it produced errors I have not been able to overcome. I have concluded Pilot6 is right, attempting to update to the latest stable version of NetworkManager is a bad idea and should not be attempted.